# Is it possible to have Netbeans generate web service from Java class?

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans-8

I do know that Netbeans can generate the Java methods from a .wsdl file.

Can Netbeans create a .wsdl file based off of a Java class and all its methods?

Tutorials such as this one
show me how to create web services manually:

> https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html

I know how to do that part. I'd like to know if there is a better, faster way to crank out web services from Java methods I already have.

Let's say I had a Java interface class that asks for 2 String inputs and returns one String:

```
public interface WeatherInterface {
    public String getWeatherInfo(String cityName, String zipCode);
}
```

I'd like to know if there is a code generator in Netbeans or some plugin that writes the web service code for me so that I don't have to add each field with the "add operation" button as shown in the tutorial link above.

I'm using Netbeans 8.0.2 with Java 7

This is what I get when I right-click on project > new > web service (select package) > finish

```
package apackage;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
@WebService(serviceName = "NewWebService")
public class NewWebService {
    /**
     * This is a sample web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
        return "Hello " + txt + " !";
    }
}
```

None of my methods from my Java class in that package were generated.... just generic "hello" method.

Thanks in advance, 
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as all my research goes, there is no tool that auto-generates web service methods from your Java methods. The web service methods are straightforward enough to create. If you have hundreds of these to make, I feel sorry for you; that's a lot of wrapping to do. Anyway, here is one of mine that I made:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "activate")
public String activate(
        @WebParam(name = "userEdipi") String userEdipi,
        @WebParam(name = "adminEdipi") String adminEdipi,
        @WebParam(name = "sarId") String sarId) {
    try {
        String response = acctmgrInterface.activate(userEdipi, adminEdipi, sarId);
        return response;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("AcctmgrWebService.activate(): error - have your admin check the server logs");
        logger.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e.fillInStackTrace()));
        return e.toString();
    }
}
```